# Set the timeOut value for NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: xcode, timeout, nsurlconnection, nsmutableurlrequest

I am trying to set the timeout value for the NSMutableURLRequest, and while debugging, I have checked that it is not working. Googled for 10 mins, and I have got the info that , the default timeout value is 240 . The following are the code which I am using right now, I guess I am missing somewhere, I want to know how to set the timeOut value for the NSMutableURLRequest

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fURL];

_urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] url];
[_urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[_urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:120];

NSURLConnection*  _urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_urlRequest delegate: self];
```

I have tried using this too `[_nsmURLRequest initWithURL:nsURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:120];` . It is not working. Any help will be thankful

Comment: Look at my answer it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466389/nsmutableurlrequest-timeout-interval-not-taken-into-consideration-for-post-reque/27962981#27962981

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1765557/1037394) post the default timeout value (240) you mentioned is also the minimum value. You'll have to use another timer to cancel the request as described in the link.

Comment: You should not use timer, see [comments and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304560/how-to-set-a-timeout-with-afnetworking#comment12884403_8304560) by [@matt](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157142/mattt) (author of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)).

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `setTimeoutInterval` BEFORE the `setHTTPMethod:@"GET"`

Comment: The above sounds more like a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If it was intended to be an answer, consider adding a bit more detail explaining how it solves the problem.