# How can I stop request(timeout) in AFNetworking if I start a request but no response data in 30seconds

Tags: ios, afnetworking

How can I stop a request(timeout) in AFNetworking if I started a request but no response data for a while such as 30 seconds

Comment: `[operation cancel];`

Comment: refere  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304560/how-to-set-a-timeout-with-afnetworking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your NSURLRequest with a timeout value that fits your needs.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL
 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];
```

Then, initialize AFNetworking's `AFHTTPRequestOperation` with that initialized NSMutableURLRequest request.

Comment: ok,it's helpful.but I don't understand why Matt who's the author of AFNetWorking use the method:NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]; but not NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:inURL
 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:30.0];?

Comment: See Matt's answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304560/how-to-set-a-timeout-with-afnetworking) question.