# ASIHttpRequest library is no longer maintained?

Tags: ios

Today, I am search libraries for handling iOS http request. I got a library named ASIHttpRequest. But when i look up it's Document. BUT! I found the first line of the website "Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)" with the blue background! And I found the words "Last updated: 15th May 2011 (v1.8.1)". Can I still use ASIHttpRequest library in my new project? Is there other something better?

Answer (score 0):

That's right ASIHTTPRequest is no longer maintained.

I consider [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to be the best HTTP library for iOS. It's documentation is really good and you should be able to get up and running very easily.

Comment: Meybe you are right! There is a standpoint here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636418/asihttprequest-vs-afnetworking-framework