# Getting response on Asynchronous and time out on synchronous call in ASIFormDataRequest iOS dev

Tags: ios, iphone, asiformdatarequest

I am calling an API in `ASIFormDataRequest` with synchronous method and its returning me time out error on each time, logged this error `Error Domain=ASIHTTPRequestErrorDomain Code=2 "The request timed out" time out seconds set to 10s, some time it shows me this error before 10s. 
But most strange is that when I changed to Asnychronous it start working fine. I know that Synchronous block every thing until it gets response and Asynchronous don't block but what are other ways to make different both of them and why this happen in my case. Here below is my code of what I am doing. Kindly suggest me or guide me why this is happen. Looking for response thanks in advance.

```
  NSString *finalStrUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SomeAPI"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *formRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalStrUrl]];
    [formRequest setTimeOutSeconds:10];
    [formRequest setRequestMethod:@"GET"];
    [formRequest setAllowCompressedResponse:NO];
    [formRequest setDefaultResponseEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

## if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0

```
    [formRequest setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
```

## endif

```
    [formRequest setDelegate:self];
    [formRequest startAsynchronous];
```

Note: This all happening in cellular Connection.

Comment: Be aware that [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is no longer supported nor recommended for new work.

Comment: @Zaph Thanks, are you talking about for iOS 7 or 8?

Comment: This support iOS 3.0 and above.

Comment: This thread{http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595809/asihttprequest-and-afnetworking-in-2013-what-to-choose} shows that this can be use in iOS 6 and iOS 7 but not confirm for iOS8.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following code to change the timeout interval. This code will set the timeout to 05  seconds:

```
[request setTimeOutSeconds:05]


[request setNumberOfTimesToRetryOnTimeout:2];
```

get the more info on this page http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Thanks, so should I use same Async or Sync with same lines what you suggest?

Comment: [request startSynchronous];

Comment: Ok I tried but same result and sorry for not mentioning that this all happening on cellular connection, I know this may has nothing to do with cellular but its only happening on cellular.