# Best way to integrate web-services in iOS in code

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services

previously i call the service from the same class when and where i need the data. is it a good approach to do it, let me know the best option to integrate web-services. Also using ASIHttpRequest framework is come under good coding standards?

Comment: Just for ASIHttpRequest part : it's not maintained anymore, look at Afnetworking http://afnetworking.com/ instead.

Comment: I agree with `Shawn` whilst `ASIHTTPRequest` framework is still good it has just become dated over the years as it is no longer maintained. Whilst AFNetworking is still a bit ruff around the edges I it is maintained and works very well. My recommendation would be to go on to the most up-to-date one out of the two. I still use `ASIHTTPRequest` but that is only because I haven't found time to move over to `AFNetworking` and `ASIHTTPRequest` has done me well over the years, but we all need to be rolling with the times.

Answer (score 0):

yes ,ASIHttpRequest framework is come under good coding standards. there are some features that missing in AFNetwork.You can check below link

[What major ASIHTTPRequest features is AFNetworking missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529258/what-major-asihttprequest-features-is-afnetworking-missing)

Comment: dont go to ASI as it is no longer supported. That cited post is from 2011

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree ASIHttpRequest framework is good and most people prefer this but its not maintained so we need to looking for some other option also.I am using AFNetworking instead of ASIHttpRequest and found it is performance wise faster than ASIHttpRequest.It is already use NSSerialization for parsing the JSON string so you need not to worry about JSON parsing.They take care of every thing we required when we are call api like JSON parsing, XML parsing, loader etc.
You can check http://www.absoluteripple.com/1/post/2013/01/using-afnetworking.html
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking