# Library / Framework to manage network call in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, mknetworkkit

I try to develop an iOS app which need a lot of network calls...

I see that there is few iOS classes provide in the SDK.

Before to start I would like to know if there are any libraries or framework which stand out of the crowd? Or can you just recommend me the most used?

I've made some research on internet and I found two frameworks `MKNetworkKit` and `ASIHTTPRequest`. Anybody know them? Are they efficient?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use** [**`AFNetworking`**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

However `ASIHTTPRequest` was also one of the best Framework to manage  Network Call but now it's not that much in use.

Even the Developers of the `ASIHTTPRequest` [says](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D;) :

> A little update: I've actually really enjoyed using AFNetworking, and
>   in many ways it's considerably better (probably not the right word:
>   'refined', maybe) than ASI. That said, you shouldn't go into it
>   expecting a 'like for like' replacement, and there are certain things
>   you may want to consider other options for (Amazon S3, which ASI
>   supported out of the box for example). But I'm generally really
>   pleased, and find it a clear, well documented library. So if you're
>   looking to move from ASI to something else, you really can't go wrong
>   with AFNetworking.

`AFNetworking` is more refined than `ASI`. Supportive [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7529258/1603072).

Comment: AFNetworking is the way to go, but depends what your needs are, RestKit may also be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use ASIHTTPRequest.

REASON:

```
  1.simple reliable and functional.
  2.easy to handle post files (ASIFormDataRequest)
  3.process provided
```

[Docs](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/)