# UIWebView doesn't always call -[NSURLCache storeCachedResponse:forRequest:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiwebview

It seems that `UIWebView` doesn't always call `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` whenever it's loading a resource. Does anyone know why? I am trying to cache images by using `-[NSURLCache storeCachedResponse:forRequest:]`, it does most of the job fine, however in some cases `UIWebView` doesn't call this method on page load where there are actually images on it.

Comment: I notice this too; though only *on* device for my app.  When the web view loads a request from the NSURLCache, it seems to skip over that very same cache for assets on that page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166422/nsurlconnection-on-ios-doesnt-try-to-cache-objects-larger-than-50kb) `NSURLConnection` doesn't call `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` if file size over 50kb(52428 bytes).
Try [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) [caching](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_a_download_cache).

Comment: I'm seeing this for small files (100s of bytes) as well.  The webview also fails to call `cachedResponseForRequest:`

Answer (score 11):

Answering the bounty provider's query:

> I'm seeing this for small files (100s of bytes) as well. The webview
>   also fails to call `cachedResponseForRequest:`

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7166422/nsurlconnection-on-ios-doesnt-try-to-cache-objects-larger-than-50kb) that addresses this behavior directly:

> Despite Apple's documentation [indicating
>   otherwise](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html),
>   `NSURLCache` on iOS doesn't do any disk (flash) caching at all. **You
>   can subclass `NSURLCache` to change the behaviour of the fetch and
>   store operations to use the disk (like
>   [`SDURLCache`](https://github.com/rs/SDURLCache) does), but due to the
>   following severe limitations of how the cache is used and implemented,
>   this doesn't work as well as you'd expect:**
>
> - `NSURLConnection` doesn't even call `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` for files over about 50KB (>= 52428
>     bytes, to be exact). This makes subclassing `NSURLCache` pointless for
>     our use (200KB images), because it won't even get to the cache. As a
>     result, we have to add caching manually at a level above
>     `NSURLConnection`.
> - **Even when one calls the NSURLCache's built-in `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` manually, it only stores the
>     response in memory if it's less than about 180KB. I tested this by
>     calling storeCachedResponse manually and seeing that the before/after
>     `currentMemoryUsage` didn't change for data lengths above about 180KB.
>     So we have to write our own LRU memory caching too.**

(Emphasis mine.)

This seems to be responsible for the behavior being called out. As [the current accepted answer points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9900008/517815), [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) is the expected workaround for this behavior.

*However,* note the caveat at the top of the page:

> Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)

You should consider relying on supported libraries or, if you prefer, contributing back to this library once it underlies your code.

Comment: Appreciate it :)  (And a great example of where I should have searched harder) - thanks for taking the time to thoroughly dig into this!

Comment: @Nevir No problem! I'm happy it was useful. :)

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the case with NSURLSession on iOS 7/8? I'm having problems getting NSURLCache to save large (~7MB) image files.

Answer (score 3):

`NSURLCache` works with two different caches: on-disk cache and in-memory cache

- Responses will be cached to in-memory cache if the response size is **under** 50kb
  and
- Responses will be cached to on-disk cache if the response size is **over** 50kb

If you initialize NSURLCache with diskPath nil then the on-disk cache will not be active and `storeCachedResponse:forRequest:` will only be called for response sizes that are under 50kb.

So configure your URLCache like this

```
[[MYCustomURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 
                          diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 
                          diskPath:@"urlcache.db"];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked HTTP status and cache headers? Expires, Cache-Control etc? Maybe a server answers with status=304 without any response body?

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse 
{
  NSLog(@"CODE: %d", ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)aResponse).statusCode);
  NSLog(@"HEADERS: %@", ((NSHTTPURLResponse *)aResponse).allHeaderFields);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how it works for a UIWebvieuw, but when you use a NSURLRequest the maximum size of the file depends on how you initialize the URLCache (initWithMemoryCapacity:(NSUInteger)memoryCapacity ...)
I just cached a 2MB file

Comment: For me, a 515KB .css file requested from UIWebView can be treated with `cachedResponseForRequest:` of a `NSURLCache` subclass initialized with `memoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:1024*1024*256`